# Execute a Apex class on salesforce flow

Tags: salesforce, apex

Hello I have a simple Apex class that now I can invoke through Saleforce Flow that is manually triggered, here's my simple code :

```
global class SlackIntegration {

    private static final String SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL = 'MY WEBHOOK URL';
    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<String> sendTestMessageToSlack(List<String> message) {
        System.debug('Hello');
        List<String> status = new List<String>();
        try {

            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL);
            request.setMethod('POST');
            request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            Map<String, Object> payload = new Map<String, Object>();
            payload.put('text', message[0]);

            String jsonPayload = JSON.serialize(payload);
            request.setBody(jsonPayload);

            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

            if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                status.add('Slack message is not sent');
            } else {
                status.add('Message sent successfully to Slack!');
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status.add('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

Here my objective is not to just send a Slack message, but a POC to be able to trigger API calls through Apex class in Saleforce flow.

Now this is working fine.

When I create a new flow that is triggered after updating or creating a record, I get this error : `You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`

I tried using @future, but this is not working (i'm new on salesforce)

Here's how I've done for the method with @future

First class that will be invoked by the flow :

```
public class AsyncSlackIntegration {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Send Slack Message')
    public static void sendTestMessageToSlack(List<String> messages) {
        String message = messages[0];
        FutureSlackIntegration.sendTestMessageToSlackAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Where FutureSlackIntegration is :

```
public class FutureSlackIntegration {

    private static final String SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL = 'MY WEBHOOK URL';
    @future
    public static void sendTestMessageToSlackAsync(String message) {
        try {
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL);
            request.setMethod('POST');
            request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            Map<String, Object> payload = new Map<String, Object>();
            payload.put('text', message);

            String jsonPayload = JSON.serialize(payload);
            request.setBody(jsonPayload);

            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

            if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                System.debug('Slack message is not sent');
            } else {
                System.debug('Message sent successfully to Slack!');
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help triggering an Apex Class in a salesforce flow that is triggered automatically after updating or creating a record please ?